# Find last value in column

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google Sheet I need to get the number in the last populated cell between J2 and J32. A new Cell is populated almost daily. For example here I need to get J27:

[image]

So far I have been doing it with 31 IF statements:

```
=IF(
J32 = "",
IF(
    J31 = "",
    IF(
        J30 = "",
        IF(
            J29 = "",
            IF(
                J28 = "",
                IF(
                    J27 = "",
                    IF(
                        J26 = "",
                        IF(
                            J25 = "",
                            IF(
                                J24 = "",
                                IF(
                                    J23 = "",
                                    IF(
                                        J22 = "",
                                        IF(
                                            J21 = "",
                                            IF(
                                                J20 = "",
                                                IF(
                                                    J19 = "",
                                                    IF(
                                                        J18 = "",
                                                        IF(
                                                            J17 = "",
                                                            IF(
                                                                J16 = "",
                                                                IF(
                                                                    J15 = "",
                                                                    IF(
                                                                        J14 = "",
                                                                        IF(
                                                                            J13 = "",
                                                                            IF(
                                                                                J12 = "",
                                                                                IF(
                                                                                    J11 = "",
                                                                                    IF(
                                                                                        J10 = "",
                                                                                        IF(
                                                                                            J9 = "",
                                                                                            IF(
                                                                                                J8 = "",
                                                                                                IF(
                                                                                                    J7 = "",
                                                                                                    IF(
                                                                                                        J6 = "",
                                                                                                        IF(
                                                                                                            J5 = "",
                                                                                                            IF(
                                                                                                                J4 = "",
                                                                                                                IF(
                                                                                                                    J3 = "",
                                                                                                                    IF(
                                                                                                                        J2 = "",
                                                                                                                        "",
                                                                                                                        J2
                                                                                                                    ),
                                                                                                                    J3
                                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                                J4
                                                                                                            ),
                                                                                                            J5
                                                                                                        ),
                                                                                                        J6
                                                                                                    ),
                                                                                                    J7
                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                J8
                                                                                            ),
                                                                                            J9
                                                                                        ),
                                                                                        J10
                                                                                    ),
                                                                                    J11
                                                                                ),
                                                                                J12
                                                                            ),
                                                                            J13
                                                                        ),
                                                                        J14
                                                                    ),
                                                                    J15
                                                                ),
                                                                J16
                                                            ),
                                                            J17
                                                        ),
                                                        J18
                                                    ),
                                                    J19
                                                ),
                                                J20
                                            ),
                                            J21
                                        ),
                                        J22
                                    ),
                                    J23
                                ),
                                J24
                            ),
                            J25
                        ),
                        J26
                    ),
                    J27
                ),
                J28
            ),
            J29
        ),
        J30
    ),
    J31
),
J32
) - Gesamt!Y$34
```

I have the suspicion that it's not giving me the correct results, as some numbers are off sometimes. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
=vlookup(1E+100,J2:J32,1)
```

though this could give an incorrect answer if any of the numbers in J2:J32 are as big or bigger than:

10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.

The assumption is that *between J2 and J32* includes both J2 and J32 in the search range.

Comment: You could use the `MAX(J2:J32)` in my answer below to overcome the need for using a very large number 1E+100

Comment: There is really no bug there, check my comments on the post below. I actually think your version is better but with the edit i.e. `=vlookup(MAX(J2:J32),J2:J32,1)`

Comment: @dfasoro I finally figured out why pnuts' answer works, by careful reading of the documentation, but I'm not sure why your modification wouldn't occasionally return the maximum number in the column instead of the last one. Wouldn't  MAX(J2:J32)+1  be a safer substitution for pnuts' huge number?

Comment: Indeed, re: typing. But picking a large number requires domain-specific knowledge. Sadly, it seems the national debt is approaching your number...

Comment: Sure. max+1 does that, guaranteed. Any specific number might someday fail when the data get updated/reimported/units change from miles to micrometers, or the universe expands again (which it seems to be doing every day). So "larger than any present" isn't good enough, for a fixed number. It needs to be "larger than any number that will ever be used in the future". I agree 1e100 comes pretty close to that for most things :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the formula: `=INDEX(J2:J32, MATCH(MAX(J2:J32),J2:J32, 1))`

Basically, it reads as find the value of the item at the position of the last match for a number less than or equal to the largest number in the range J2:J32.

INDEX: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472
MATCH: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378

Comment: Your formula works as well. I just choose @pnuts answer as correct since his formula is smaller.

Comment: @mles Thanks, the reason for the `MAX(J2:J32)` in my answer to overcome the need for using a very large number 1E+100

Comment: @pnuts there is a fourth parameter that takes care of that in VLOOKUP called is_sorted (defaults to TRUE) If is_sorted is TRUE or omitted, the nearest match (less than or equal to the search key) is returned. If all values in the search column are greater than the search key, #N/A is returned. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en That is actually why your code works:

Comment: The is_sorted = TRUE in VLOOKUP also does the same job as search_type = 1 which is the third parameter of the MATCH function. search_type if 1, the default, causes MATCH to assume that the range is sorted in ascending order and return the largest value less than or equal to search_key. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472