# Very complex Excel Formulas?

Tags: excel

How I can write a very complex Excel Formula?

Usually Excel Formulas are like this: `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text)), "Yes", "No")`.

How I can write a huge formula about 300 lines of code having many:

```
1) conditional statements
2) loops
3) calling other formulas
```

It's important to have a readable code and not a one lines mess.
Of course excel is not the write tool for this job but I have a very old application and I can't afford to rewrite it.

Comment: Use vba modules and functions to break it down and make it maintainable?  I would think `program` rather than `formula` or `function` if it was that complex.

Comment: It would be easier to understand and give an answer if you provided some data and expected outcome.  There may be easier methods.

Comment: Complex tells us nothing. And 300 lines of code tells us even less.  Being that you are talking lines of code you really are talking about using VBA. Its not about how many lines it is, its how efficient and correct it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) conditional statements

[IF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) but nested IFs soon get difficult to write and difficult to read/adjust. A standard alternative is to replace a series of IFs with a lookup table.  Although for Google Sheets there happens to be a rather extreme example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260890/find-last-value-in-column) (ie from nearly 500 characters down to 25).

> 2) loops

Other than via UDF, out of the question.

> 3) calling other formulas

Possibly the key. Break each element so for your example:

```
=SEARCH(substring,text)
```

in one cell (say B1) then refer to that result in your formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1), "Yes", "No")
```

This can be repeated across many cells where the formula is complex.

For your specific example, another option would be to rely on default output (TRUE / FALSE) rather than "Yes" / "No":

```
 =ISNUMBER(B1)
```

So from 48 characters to 23+13, and easier to follow.

Naming ranges can also be very helpful.